# Error running MyProjectName []: No task to execute is specified

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image]I have installed new android studio and Imported my existing android project. whenever I run the app I get "Error running MyProjectName []: No task to execute is specified"

> > 7:23 PM Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>
> 7:24 PM   Gradle build finished in 38s 639ms
>
> 7:26 PM   Error running MyProjectName []: No task to execute is specified

I have tried to resolve the error with no luck can anyone help?

Comment: I tried dotnet restore, project clean and rebuild with luck

Comment: Can you attach snapshot of error with your studio projects?

Comment: Thats is th only error I get

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html This can help, otherwise need a screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the solution the error went away but no apk generate.

**Solution I found**

GO **run -> run ->  then choose app**, not your project name as image show below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Expand the `app` element on the right side. Find the `installDebug` task, and run that

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It runs the project on a connected device

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem after opening an old project and then opening my current one. I resolved that by opening completely another project in the same window, then opening again the problematic one.

I'm not sure what caused that problem but looks like it got refreshed when I opened another, working project in the same window.